# URL Rewriting and Laravel 4 Routes not working on server?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I bet this question has been asked time and time again, but I just can't seem to get an answer. Anyway, here is my situation. I have a domain, lets say example.com. Example.com works fine, everything works as it should. However, if I navigate to Example.com/about, which works on my local machine, I get a 404 error. However, if I go to example.com/index.php/about, the about page works fine. I know this must be a mod rewrite issue. I have enabled mod rewrite and restarted my server to no avail. Anyway, here is some code:

Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/example/public"
  <Directory "/var/www/example/public">
    AllowOverride all
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Digital Ocean Droplet.

Thanks!

Comment: Quick question, is the .htaccess in the `/var/www/example/public` directory or in the `/var/www/example/` ?  Also check the file permisions on the .htaccess file as it may not be reachable by php.

Comment: It is in /var/www/example/public

Comment: So I would bet that it is a file permission issue.  I've had this happened to me with Laravel before.  Depending on where and how you do the chmod, chown, it is very likely that you did not include the .htaccess which is hidden because it starts with a .

Comment: What should I change the .htaccess file permissions to?

Comment: Something that the php server can have access to.  What are your current file permissions?    `ls -l -a`

Comment: It says 356, I tried changing it to 777 but that didn't seem to work...

Comment: Whoops, wrong data point, permissions are -rwxrwxrwx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76490/discussion-between-arturo-alvarado-and-codeforfood).

Answer (score 0):

**1)
go to /etc/apache2/sites-available and create file and add below**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@newyear
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/example/public>
        options Indexes FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**2) Create Link of above created file and paste it into /etc/apache2/sites-enabled**

**3)** Check /etc/apache2/mods-available for `rewrite.load` file 
if it is not there create it and add below line & save

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

create link of rewrite.load file and paste it into `etc/apache2/mods-enabled`

**4) open /etc/hosts**
add below

```
127.0.0.1    example.com
```

**5)** `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: you can do that right click on the file and `Make Link` if you don't have permission to do that open file manager root mode using this command 
`sudo nautilus' and do it :)

Comment: I can only use the command line on my server, will it still work there?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this, I had to put my VirtualHost code in sites-enabled, not sites-available. Facepalm.

Comment: convention is create a file in  `sites-available` and put link to that file in `sites-enabled` you can do that using `ln -s path_to_file Path_to_link_location` check my answer again

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 14.04 with apache2 i was fall this problem.Then i solve this and wrote a blog,you can follow this
http://www.kingpabel.com/apache-mod_rewrite/